# Did JFK say that "you can win with half the people's votes but cannot govern with half against you"?

Tags: quotes, jfk

According to [Al Jazeera](http://m.aljazeera.com/story/2014316184216390374):

> Jose Miguel, president of the Institute of Legal Medicine, told Al Jazeera: "The most worrying thing is the intolerance and deep divisions within the population, so the biggest challenge for the new government is to reduce this polarisation.
>
> "John F Kennedy’s phrase about how you can win with half the people's votes but cannot govern with half against you, is particularly true in our country."

Many people on Facebook and [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/perpetuok/status/434438827109675008) have posted it, translated to Spanish as:

> Se puede ganar con la mitad, pero no se puede gobernar con la otra mitad en contra

Did Kennedy say this?